# In Excel, doing a "Freeze Panes" on the right-most column instead of the left-most?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, spreadsheet, worksheet-function

My understanding of Excel's "Freeze Panes" feature is that you can only freeze the left-most column(s), or top-most row(s).

However, I have a table where a very important column needs to be located on the far-*right*, because elsewhere I am using the `VLOOKUP` function to pull data from this table.

Having this column on the far-right makes like easy on the function end... but since there are so many columns in the table, this layout makes life harder for the user on the data-entry end.

Is there any trick or technique by which I could achieve the same *effect* as "Freeze Panes" for this far-right column?  That is, have the right-most column always appear on the screen, as the user scrolls horizontally across the other columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered *splitting* instead of freezing?

Splitting has a similar effect and works in a similar way, except that the sections can be resized on the fly and can each be scrolled (almost) independantly.

When you enable splitting (same menu as freezing in Excel2003, don't know about others) make sure the selected cell is in the correct place to save yourself having to realign the split (the same as you do when freezing).