# Excel - Vertical scroll columns A, B, C, D, E but F, G, H stay the same?

Tags: microsoft-excel, scrolling

I know I can split at column F and each will scroll individually *horizontally* but I want them to independently scroll *vertically*.  Is this possible?

[Here is a fiddle of an example of what I want in HTML/css](https://jsfiddle.net/fxzpabca/)

[image]

Here is a screencap of my spreadsheet just so you guys can get an idea of why I'm trying to do this:

[image]

Ideally it wouldn't even have two scrollbars.  The right few columns would just stick where they are (they would never need to be scrolled).

I don't believe this is a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/238072) for two reasons: First, his requirements are only to "freeze" the right-most column.  I need multiple.  Second, the accepted solution is the "split" option, which as I stated above only allows independent horizontal scrolling, not vertical as I require.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Excel, doing a "Freeze Panes" on the right-most column instead of the left-most?](http://superuser.com/questions/238072/in-excel-doing-a-freeze-panes-on-the-right-most-column-instead-of-the-left-mo)

Comment: Two differences: That one only requires 1 column.  Also, the accepted answer is to use the "split" feature, which as far as I can tell only allows independent horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know is *View -> New Window* , and then *Arrange All -> Vertical*.

You will have *two windows of the same worksheet* so you can move horizontally and vertically on each window independently of the other window.